# Precisa indicar a quantidade de vezes que o maior número foi lido, mas não está contando isso

Tags: c, algoritmo

Não estou conseguindo descobrir a quantidade de vezes que um determinado número maior foi lido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    int i, num, maior = 0;

    printf ("Ao finalizar, digite '00', sem aspas, para obter o resultado.\n\n");

    i = 1;
    do
    {
        printf ("Insira um numero: ");
        scanf  ("%d", &num);

        if (num == 00)
            break;

        else
        {
            if (num > maior)
            {
                maior = num;
                i++;
            }
            else
                if (num < maior)
                printf ("Erro: Numero invalido. ");
        }

    }
    while (num != 0);

    printf ("Maior numero: %d\n", maior);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem a questão. Você precisa contabilizar a quantidade de vezes que o "recorde" foi quebrado? Ou contar a quantidade de números lidos até que o "recorde" seja quebrado?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

A não ser que tenha algo que não está na pergunta, essa de número inválido não faz sentido. Por que o número ser menor seria inválido? Até pode acontecer invalidade do número e seria legal tratar isso, mas como é exercício eu deixo pra lá, só não tome como correto para códigos reais.

Na sua conta está contando quantas vezes o número maior foi trocado, afinal está incrementando um contador toda vez que encontrou um novo maior. Não é oque está na pergunta. Quando troca por uma número maior a contagem deve começar de novo por nesse momento esse número maior só apareceu uma vez. Isso chama-se lógica. Quando o número é igual ao maior então aí deve incrementar o contador. Se o número for menor é para fazer nada.

Não dá para pedir para a pessoa digitar 00, isso não é um texto, 00 é o mesmo que 0. Ou até dá mas aí teria que pedir um texto e depois fazer a conversão, dá muito trabalho. Talvez fosse o caso para pedir um número negativo para sair do laço, se puder um negativo também, aí complica e teria que ter outra solução de saída.

O teste que fazia não impedia ninguém digitar algo negativo como um valor válido.

Dei uma organizada e simplificada também.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int quantidade = 0, maior = 0;
    printf("Ao finalizar, digite '0', sem aspas, para obter o resultado.\n\n");
    while (1) {
        printf("Insira um numero: ");
        int num;
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (!num) break;
        if (num > maior) {
            maior = num;
            quantidade = 1;
        } else if (num == maior) quantidade++;
    }
    printf("Maior numero: %d - quantidade de vezes: %d\n", maior, quantidade);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1c3S5T). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xdzstxle-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CountGreater.c).

Comment: Simplifiquei a pergunta apenas, para que ficasse mais objetiva. O fato de ter colocado "número inválido", se refere a questão proposta, em que foi pedido somente números positivos. A fim de deixar algo mais claro para o usuário, optei por colocar está mensagem. Sim, é somente um exercício, não é nada profissional. O objetivo é para somente aprender um pouco mais sobre o mundo da programação. Desde já, agradeço a sua atenção.

Comment: Portanto é um erro, ali não está testando se é positivo, em lugar algum está. Você não simplificou a pergunta, você deixou de colocar os requisitos, aí quem responde tem que adivinhar. Veja o [tour] para entender como o site funciona e o que deve fazer quando a resposta resolveu seu problema.